# An inequality from Littlewood's Miscellany

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

Why is the following inequality from Chapter 1 of Littlewood's [A Mathematician's Miscellany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Miscellany) true?

> Suppose $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Then $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n\geq e.$$

Comment: Littlewood credits Polya with this this result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Leshik's proof, but spelled out a bit more.

**Lemma 1**: If $0<x<e$ then for sufficiently large $n$, $x^{1/n}<1+1/n$.

**Proof**: I'll leave this for you for now.

**Lemma 2**: Given any sequence $c_n$, if $\limsup c_n < x$ then for sufficiently large $n$, $c_n<x$.

**Proof**: This is practically the definition of $\limsup$.

**Main proof**: Let $c_n = \left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n$. We proceed to prove by contradiction. Assume $\limsup c_n < e$. Then let $b$ be some value such that $\limsup c_n < b< e$.

Now, for large enough $n$, $b > c_n=\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n$  by lemma 2, and $b^{1/n}<1+1/n$, by lemma 1, which gets us to the step that Leshik gets:

$$\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n} < b^{1/n} < 1+1/n$$

for sufficiently large $n$. The rest of Leshik's proof is fairly clear - you proceed to show that some $a_i$ must be negative, thus reaching a contradiction, and so our assumption cannot be true, and you are done.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for this. It is very helpful indeed +1. I'd been trying to solve it for a long time.  I think that Lemma 2 needs one small clarification: it is not true just for sufficiently large $n$ rather for sufficiently large values of $n$. Anyways, I was wondering if it could be proven by taking log and simplifying fractions to summations. I tried with that but didn't get contradiction.

Comment: The difference between "sufficiently large value of $n$" and "sufficiently large values of $n$" is basically "$\exists $N_1$ $ such that statement is true for $n=N_1$" and "$\exists N: n\ge N\implies $ statement is true for all $n\ge N$" respectively.

Comment: @Koro Personally, I take “for sufficiently large $n$“ to always mean that, for some $N$, all $n>N.$ If it implied only one such $n,$ then your term would only imply more than one such $n,$ which would also be misleading. And I didn’t say “value.”

Comment: In that case, I don't have any issue. It seems that both terms are misleading "for sufficiently large values of $n$" or "sufficiently large value of $n$" however if the idea behind the usage of these terms is made explicit then there is no issue/ ambiguity at all.

Comment: I don't quite understand why it has to be $\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$? Can it just be $\frac{1+a_{m}}{a_{n}}$? It looks like $\{a_{n}\}$ is quite arbitrary..

Answer (score 12):

Suppose that the upper limit is $c<e.$ Then for sufficiently large $n$ and $b<e$ we have 
$$\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le b^{1/n}\le {\frac{n+1}{n}}.$$ 
Introducing $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n},$ we can rewrite the last inequality as
$$b_{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}\le b_n.$$
Iterating last inequality we arrive at
$$b_{n+m}\le b_n-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{n+k}.$$
The only thing left is to note that harmonic series diverges and the right hand side can be made negative for sufficiently large $m.$

Comment: But maybe that sequence hasn't limit.

Comment: we do not need s limit, just the upper limit.

Comment: What happened to $c$?

Comment: well, since $(1+1/n)^n$ converges to $e,$ then for each $b<e$ starting from some $n$ the inequality mentioned above has to be valid.

Comment: your $c$ is the limit or upper limit..?

Comment: It should be added that $b=\frac{e+c}2$ for example (or any value strictly between $c$ and $e$.

Comment: @MherSafaryan See my pevious ocmment - OR note that the negation of $\limsup x_n\ge e$ is: There exists $b<e$ such that $x_n<b$ for almost all $n$.

Comment: yes, we assume $c\le b<e.$

Comment: If $c=b$ then you don't know that inequality. You need $c<b$. @leshik .

Comment: i claim that such $b$ exists, so I do not need to request the strict inequality.

Comment: But in a proof, we don't "claim," we show. It would be easy to edit this proof to make it clearer and an excellent answer, but you jump around. You don't even assert "there exists a $b$," you just suddenly use the letter $b$ as if the reader knows what you are saying.

Comment: I usually tend to leave some details for the reader. In case the proposer or someone else has questions, I am always willing to clarify things. I can see no point been picky about smth. when you actually understand what is going on, unless something is written in a wrong way.

Comment: Leaving something to the reader and skipping past the definition of a variable are very different things, especially when the reader has no idea if you are right.